# C# to F#: Creating and using a float[][] in F#

Tags: c#, arrays, machine-learning, f#, neural-network

I have this simple method for a neural network in C#:

```
  private void InitNeurons()
    {
        //Neuron Initilization
        List<float[]> neuronsList = new List<float[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _layers.Length; i++) //run through all layers
        {
            neuronsList.Add(new float[_layers[i]]); //add layer to neuron list
        }

        _neurons = neuronsList.ToArray(); //convert list to array
    }
```

How do I do this in F#?  I was thinking it could be simpler.  Perhaps something like this?

```
namespace NeuralNetwork

type NeuralNetworkF(layers : int[]) = 
    member this.Layers = layers
    member this.Neurons : float[][] = [| for layer in layers do new float[]|]
```

This causes a compiler error in F#.  I want to take the size of the int array "_layers" and for each value iterate over and add that value to the Neurons member in F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're trying to create an array `new float[]` is not valid syntax in F#. The correct syntax for an array is `[| 1; 2; 3 |]`, or for empty array it would be just `[| |]`. The type of elements does not need to be specified, the compiler will infer it from the context. But if you *really* want to be explicit, you can still specify the type via a colon, like you can with any expression: `[| |] : float[]`.

However, that is all useless to you anyway, because what you're trying to do is not create an array with known elements, but create an array of a known length. For that, there are a few functions, and the one that would be useful to you here is `Array.create`. It takes two arguments - the size and the value, - and it returns an array of that size, where every element is that value.

```
type NeuralNetworkF(layers : int[]) = 
    member this.Layers = layers
    member this.Neurons : float[][] = [| for layer in layers -> Array.create layer 0.0 |]
```

Note that in the code above I've also replaced `do` with `->`. This is the second problem you had. You see, `do` performs an "action", which does not necessarily result in an item, e.g.:

```
let xs = [ for n in 1..10 do 
             if n > 5 then yield n ]
```

This will produce a list of numbers `6` to `10` - not `1` to `10` - because it only produces an element when `n > 5`. The `yield` keyword is what produces an element. So, if you wanted to produce an array for every layer in your code, you'd have to `yield` that array:

```
[| for layer in layers do yield Array.create layer 0.0 |]
```

This works, but there is a shortcut: the arrow `->` stands for `do yield`, so you can use it instead.

```
[| for layer in layers -> Array.create layer 0.0 |]
```

**Finally**, a question to you: do you really need a class? Classes are wibbly-wobbly-timey-whimey, so unless you have a good reason, I recommend going with a record.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I probably don't need a class.  I'm new to F# and functional programming in general.  I was hoping that writing the neural network in F# would make it easier to understand as c# makes it very verbose.

Answer (score 4):

Nice explanation there, @FyodorSoikin, but the following is probably even nicer:

```
let newNeuralNetwork (layers : _ []) =
    fun i -> Array.zeroCreate<float> layers.[i]
    |> Array.init layers.Length
```